# Gem installed successfully, but now I can't require it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, websocket, rubygems

I'm using the Slack for ruby gem (`slack-ruby-client`) and part of its prerequisites is to install the `faye-websocket` gem.

In my Gemfile, I have the following:

```
# Slack-ruby-client
gem 'slack-ruby-client'
gem 'eventmachine'
gem 'websocket-driver'
gem 'faye-websocket'
gem 'rails_best_practices'
```

However, my Ruby container doesn't seem to like the `websocket-driver` gem. For example, when `docker-compose up` runs, the container runs the `entrypoint.sh` file, which just does a `bundle install`. Afterwards, it tries to execute `rails s --binding 0.0.0.0`. This crashes because it cannot load the `websocket/driver` Gem, as shown below:

```
sidekiq_1   | LoadError: cannot load such file -- websocket/driver
sidekiq_1   |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
sidekiq_1   |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
sidekiq_1   |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:89:in `register'
sidekiq_1   |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
sidekiq_1   |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:41:in `rescue in require'
sidekiq_1   |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:27:in `require'
sidekiq_1   |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
```

If I get a shell within the container by running the following command:

```
docker exec -ti sidekiq_app_1 /bin/sh
```

The gem installs just perfectly fine running `gem install websocket-drivr`, as shown below:

```
/myapp # gem install websocket-driver
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed websocket-driver-0.7.2
1 gem installed
```

But if I open up a ruby console and try to actually require it, it gives me an error, as shown below:

```
/myapp # irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'websocket-driver'
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from /usr/local/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
        3: from (irb):1
        2: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        1: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
LoadError (cannot load such file -- websocket-driver)
irb(main):002:0> exit
```

```
 myuser@ubuntu  ~/Documents/app   dev ●  docker exec -ti sidekiq_app_1 rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 241
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.4)
irb(main):001:0> require 'websocket-driver'
require 'websocket-driver'
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
LoadError (cannot load such file -- websocket-driver)
irb(main):002:0>
```

If I run `gem list | grep -i websocket` on the container, I get the following output:

```
/myapp # gem list | grep -i websocket-driver
websocket-driver (0.7.2)
```

From within the `irb` console, I can successfully `require 'websocket/driver'` with no problem, but if I run the same thing from within the `rails c` prompt, then it returns `false`:

```
/myapp # irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'websocket/driver'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> exit
/myapp # rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 376
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.4)
irb(main):001:0> require 'websocket/driver'
require 'websocket/driver'
=> false
irb(main):002:0> quit
quit
/myapp #
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1-alpine
ENV BUNDLER_VERSION=2.0.2

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
        binutils-gold \
        build-base \
        curl \
        file \
        g++ \
        gcc \
        git \
        less \
        libstdc++ \
        libffi-dev \
        libc-dev \ 
        linux-headers \
        libxml2-dev \
        libxslt-dev \
        libgcrypt-dev \
        make \
        netcat-openbsd \
        nodejs \
        openssl \
        pkgconfig \
        postgresql-dev \
        python \
        tzdata \
        yarn 

RUN gem install bundler -v 2.0.2
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
RUN bundle check || bundle install

COPY . /myapp
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 80

CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "80"]
```

entrypoint.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh
bundle install
rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
npm install
set -e

rm -f /myapp/tmp/pids/server.pid

exec "$@"
```

docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
      - gem_cache:/usr/local/bundle/gems
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
    env_file: .env

  database:
    image: postgres:12.1
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file: .env

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.7
    env_file: .env

  sidekiq:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.sidekiq
    depends_on:
      - app
      - database
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
      - gem_cache:/usr/local/bundle/gems
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
    env_file: .env

volumes:
  gem_cache:
  db_data:
  node_modules:
```

Why would this happen if it *just* installed the gem successfully?

Comment: Can you find `websocket-driver` by typing in your terminal: `gem list`?

Comment: According to their documentation, you should require it by `require 'websocket/driver'` https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/websocket-driver

Comment: If I try that -- `require 'websocket/driver'` it just says `false`, although the gem is installed. If I run a `gem list`, It shows `websocket-driver (0.7.2)` in the list

Comment: There's some Docker hints in here; how are you launching the container?  (You mention you run `bundle install` in an entrypoint script; why re-run that command every time you start the container, instead of doing it once in the Dockerfile?)

Comment: How many ruby and irb binaries do you have in the container?

Comment: @D.SM That's all I have. I'll update and post my Dockerfile and entrypoint as well.

Comment: Run `find / -name ruby` to find otu.

Comment: _require **says** false_ : What do you mean by this? That the `require` method returns `false`? This is not an error, but just says that the file has already been required. `require 'X'` returns `true` the first time, and `false` on each subsequent invocation.